# Custom UIAlertView moved up after upgrading to ipad/universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, uialertview, universal

So after upgrading to a universal app, one of my UIAlertViews shifted up, but only for the iOS4.0.

Before:

[Valid XHTML http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/4959/screenshot20100719at156.png](http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/4959/screenshot20100719at156.png).

After (only on iOS4.0):

[Valid XHTML http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/4959/screenshot20100719at156.png](http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/4959/screenshot20100719at156.png).

I looked into

```
alert.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate( alert.transform, 0.0, -100.0 );
```

to shift it back down, but that does absolutely nothing. Does anyone else have this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the size of the frame of the uitextfield ? you know adding one to a uialertview is not exactly supported right

Answer (score 0):

I hope by this time you would have found the solution for the problem, nevertheless I found one solution but that was regarding iPhone although would be relevant for your problem as well. The link is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184824/positioning-subclassed-uialertview-window-with-onscreen-keyboard-on-ios).

Hope t still helps!!